# I get this error android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "x": in insert statement

Tags: sqlite, sql-insert

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "x": syntax error: INSERT INTO  items (product_title, flexible, product_qty, likes, dislikes, skip)  Values (1/3 x Medium Veg Box, '0', '1', '', '', '');

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query syntax is wrong:

**1/3 x Medium Veg Box should be in quotes**

It should be

```
INSERT INTO items (product_title, flexible, product_qty, likes, dislikes, skip) Values ('1/3 x Medium Veg Box', '0', '1', '', '', '');
```